# Is it possible remove span element node around text node without interrupting the cursor?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following structure:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <span class="some-class">Hello</span>
    World <!-- no span here -->
    <span class="some-other-class">and good bye!</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible to remove selected span elements, but not the text node, without interrupting the cursor position in the `contenteditable` `div`?

So even if the cursor is inside the span, keep the same text content, but just remove the span elements around it

For example if the styling of `some-class` is red text color and I put the cursor somewhere inside the word "Hello", then I want the styling to be gone and remove the wrapping `span`

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go!

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    <span class="some-class" style="color: red">Hello</span>
    <span class="some-class" style="color: blue">world</span>
    <span class="some-other-class" style="color: orange">and good bye!</span>
    <span style="color: green">test</span>
</div>

<script>
    const div = document.querySelector('div');

    const getSelection = () => {
        let offset = 0;
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        let start = range.startOffset;
        let end = range.endOffset;

        if (selection.baseNode.parentNode.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (const node of selection.baseNode.parentNode.childNodes) {
                const cnode = node;
                if (cnode.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE && !(offset + cnode.length > start)) {
                    offset = offset + cnode.length;
                }
                if (cnode.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE && !(offset + cnode.textContent.length > start)) {
                    offset = offset + cnode.textContent.length;
                }
            }
        }

        start = start + offset;
        end = end + offset;

        return { start, end };
    };

    const removeSpan = ({ target, currentTarget: { selectionStart } }) => {
        // Get our selection points for within our span element
        const { start, end } = getSelection();

        // Only run this logic for span elements
        if (target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
            // Create new text node from our span's innerText
            const text = document.createTextNode(target.innerText + ' ');

            // Replace span with just the text
            target.replaceWith(text);

            // Create a range and set selection range back to what it was to not affect cursor
            const range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(text, start);
            range.setEnd(text, end);

            const selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    };

    div.addEventListener('click', removeSpan);
</script>
```

Comment: That looks great. But I encountered a boundary case: Click somewhere on the word `test`, then click somewhere on `and good bye!` and then put the cursor at the end of the word `world` (after the letter `d`) - there is an `Uncaught IndexSizeError`. Any idea why?

Comment: @B.DLiroy I'm not experiencing the same error with your test case, but I've gotten it before. The reason is that we're for some reason sometimes setting the start point of the selection range within a textnode to be greater than the text node's length. From what I've seen this error doesn't affect the functionality.  Perhaps you can fix it since this code is already 99% what you want :)